# Log in On site With two Folder creating Error

Tags: php, session, authentication

I have database with two different names. But structure (columns etc) is the same

I have two folders in root which are serving as two different sites.
e.g in root folder of `www.xyz.com` , there are two folders

```
 xyz.com/firstsite/index.php

 xyz.com/secondsite/index.php
```

Now Both folders have login system for specific files in that folder.

My problem is as follows...

If I login in `www.xyz.com/firstsite` I go to successful login page. Now if I try opening  `www.xyz.com/secondsite` in another tab of same browser, it shows `You are already in Logged In` instead of username and password fields.

As Both login systems fetches data from two different databases...till why you are already logged in message is seen ?

Comment: i think your session is same that conflict is see in there.

Answer (score 0):

You probably are assigning the same session/cookie names when logging in and then obviously checking for them/the same names when checking users' login status on both sites.

Check in your login scripts and your check login status or your session status scripts and see what you are naming the sessions.

Example:

Folder 1 is the admin page and requires admin privileges.

Folder 2 is the employee page and requires employee privileges.

At the top of every public web-file in both folders you include a script that checks for their session/cookie values. Then you check those against the users table of your database and where there is a match you check to see what their privileges are, or what their user level is.

If a user has a session/cookie named "user_id" with a value of '1', and another named "user_name" with a value of "JimBob", and tries to log into the admin section of your website, then you check the `userlevel` column in your DB where the user_id='1' and user_name='JimBob'.

Let's say you set the value of the user level column equal to 'A' when they have admin privileges. If JimBob's user level equals 'E' or anything other than 'A' then you header/redirect them to the login page, or your admin login page since they tried to access admin pages.

All you really need to do is have a database with a table named `users`, for example, that has a column named `userlevel`.

Then you can assign users with a specific user-level depending on the site privileges they require and grant them access accordingly.

When some one tries to access a page, you check the session/cookies you set for them in your login script and query your database for a match and grant access or redirect them accordingly.

Comment: should i give name to session in both folders or problem will be solved after giving session name to one folder login only

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this problem by changing the names of the Session variables in the sites.

You can do it like this:

```
$_SESSION['site1']['user']=array(user details...);
$_SESSION['site2']['user']=array(user details..);
```

And in the login page you could easily find out the user information using the correct site variable in the session.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution for this as following...

I added session_name(xyz) in one folder (say site 2)

And Just Changed

```
     $_SESSION=['user_id']
```

to

```
     $_SESSION=['user_id2']
```

in pages, login page of site 2.